# Error when generating access token for Facebook messaging app

Tags: facebook, chatbot, facebook-messenger

Despite googling and asking around I cannot find an answer to hat I am doing wrong.

I have a Facebook account and a Facebook developer account.

I created a page with my Facebook account

I log into FB developer page and create an app.

I give it a name and email and verify I am not a robot. I have a app id.

I go to dashboard and note I am in development mode.

I add a product - messenger to add te FB messaging to my page where I'll have my chat bot app.

To generate an Access Token I select the page I created from the drop down.

In the tutorial I  am following an Access Token appears in the right had input.

But I get the following error

*'lease edit permissions to grant the app pages_messaging in order to generate an access token.'*

[image]

Can anyone tell me why  and / or how to solve this issue.

Please note when I click edit permissions I see a prompt to get my permission changes reviewed by Facebook , but I should not need to do that as my app is in develop mode and will not be available to general FB users, as I understand it.

Here is a screen shot of what I see after clicking edit permissions

[image]

Thanks for your time . Much appreciated.

Comment: so...did you click on "edit permissions"?

Comment: You were correct , I was confused when I saw the submit for login review. In fact , for anyone else out there just The process is simple however, just click on Edit Permissions > Select the page (deselect all others) > Make sure the checkbox is enabled and hit next and complete. This should generate the PAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies , I was confused when I saw the login permissions and thought I'd have to request fB to review my app , while it was still in deveopment mode.  In fact you can follow the instructions below. Although I have no idea why iy just doesn't fill in the Access Token as it used to , the additional step seems pretty redundant and confusing (IMHO).

The process is simple however, just click on Edit Permissions > Select the ChatMiester page (deselect all others) > Make sure the checkbox is enabled and hit next and complete. This should generate the PAT. Having said this, I could not replicate this at my end, but it should work easily.